# There seem to be no try/catch errors when making a cts.collectionQuery on a nonexistent collection

Tags: runtime-error, marklogic-9

I have a MarkLogic JavaScript query using the cts.collectionQuery using the Query Console. I'm looking for a way to detect if an invalid (nonexistent) collection is passed to the query.  Wrapping the code in a try/catch block doesn't do anything useful and always returns a result which seems to be bad behavior.

In the following snippet, the value for "thisCollection" can be anything and the query will return a value without error.

```
try {
  var thisCollection = "xxxx";
  var collQuery = cts.collectionQuery(thisCollection);
  var phoneQuery = cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("phoneNumber", number);
  var andQuery = cts.andQuery([collQuery, phoneQuery]);
  var thisCount = cts.estimate(andQuery);
  resultCount = resultCount + thisCount;
  resultString = resultString + "," + thisCount;
} catch(err) {
  resultString = "Query Error =" + err.name;
}
```

My expectation is that passing a nonexistent collection name to a collectionQuery would throw an error of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to understand that collections are just kind of labels attached to documents. They exist by the mere use of them on documents, and don't need to be pre-declared in any way. That is also why one document can participate in many collections, as opposed to the fact it can be in only one directory (or path).

Best way to detect if a collection 'exists', is by doing a cts.estimate on it:

```
let collectionExists = cts.estimate(collQuery) > 0;
```

HTH!

Comment: Yep, thanks.  That approach will work for me.  Appreciate the help.